# Proving a partial fraction decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer, $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree lower than $n$. Prove, if $a$ is real and $a \neq 0$ then:
>
> $$\frac{P(x)}{(ax+b)^n} = \frac{c_1}{ax+b} + \frac{c_2}{(ax+b)^2} + \dots + \frac{c_n}{(ax+b)^n}$$
>
> for some constants $c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n$.

I know that I should use Taylor's expansion for $P(x)$ but I have no idea how to do this exercise. I will be grateful for any help...

Comment: OK, so P(x) = $c_{1}(ax+b)^{n-1}+...+c_n$ so as I know that degree of P(x) is max n-1 then I should find correct c, that's right? And how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you know about taylor expansions, then you can simply expand $P$ around the point $\frac{b}{a}$ which will give you

$$P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i \left(x-\frac{b}{a}\right)^i.$$

Use the fact that $P$ is a polynomial of degre $<n$ to prove that $a_i=0$ for $i\geq n$. And change the elements into $$a_i\left(x-\frac{b}{a}\right)^i = \frac{a_i}{a}\left(ax-b\right)^i.$$